# django template internal url concatenation

Tags: django

In my django project, I have URL patterns like below.

urls.py in project root:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

urls.py in app(blog) root:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path(
        'category/<str:category_id>',
        views.category_view, 
        name='category_view',
    ),
]
```

What I want to do is making hyperlink for each category with django template. Something like below.

```
{% for category in categories %} .
    <a href="{{ {% url 'index' %}|add: {% url 'category_view' category %} }} " class="nav">
        {{category}}
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

However, it doesn't work. There are too many categories that I can't hard code any of them, but have to make url "(domain root)/category/(category name)" with django template. How can I concatinate two url in a template (as django does with

```
path(A, include(B))
```

)

Comment: I can't understand why you think you need to concatenate the URLs. The url for your category page is just `{% url 'category_view' category %} `, no need to add anything.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, Of course, I tried that one. However, it doesn't work properly by giving me only "category/(category_name)" without the front part. That's why I'm trying to add front part, which is domain URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `get_absolute_url` method in your Category model, it is a much cleaner solution: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url

Implementation example:

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
# for django < 1.10 from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

class Category(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse_lazy('category_view', category_id=self.id)
```

and in your template:

```
{% for category in categories %} .
    <a href="{{ category.get_absolute_url }}" class="nav">
        {{category}}
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```